# using 2 select() with 1 file descriptor or using dup(fd)

Tags: multithreading, select, concurrency

I'd like to wakeup 2 threads, blocked in 2 select(), using the same 1 fd (with R_ONLY) 
or using 1 fd and a duplicate of this fd dup(fd)

```
int fd1(R_Only);
int fd2 = dup(fd1);

//Thread1
result = select(fd1);
if (result)
   printf("test1");

//Thread2
result = select(fd2);
if (result)
   printf("test2");
```

my expected results are that everytime fd1 is ready to be read, I have something like this: ( | (pipe) representing fd1 ready to be read)

```
| test1 test2 | test1 test2 | test2 test1 | test1 test2 | test2 test1 ...
```

but it's seems that those select() are still concurrent, and my current results are:

```
| test1 | test2 | test2 | test1 | test1 | test1 | test.......
```

only one thread woke up at a time...

I don't expect any order between threads: just to wake up , do things and blocked.

Also I can't control or recode thread1 (not mine), I just have a way to get back the desired fd on which I can sync thread2.

Is there a way to do this or i'm stuck ?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

The `dup` syscall duplicates the file descriptor in a way so that `fd1` and `fd2` still refer to the same entry in the process file descriptor table.

While the behavior of `select` could be implementation-dependent in this scenario, it is reasonable to think that you cannot wake up two threads with an event on the same file descriptor or, even if possible, only one of the threads would be able to consume the available data.